# Changing a State variable from onAppear and onTapGesture

Tags: swiftui, state

So my problem is that I have an overlay, where I built a small custom notification window. It gets shown after a certain action was initiated by the user and executed. I planned to deactivate this custom notification by setting the bool State variable to false either after 2 seconds by itself (onAppear), or by tapping anywhere on the screen (onTapGesture).

One at a time works fine, but if I set showAlert to false in both onAppear and onTapGesture, the tapGesture does get executed, but the overlay does not get deactivated, by tapping. I know that two gestures at once do not work on the same object without simultaneous Gestures. But onAppear is no gesture and both get executed, just the State changing mechanism does not. Can someone lead me to an answer, why exactly this is the case and how to resolve this. I can imagine, that the delayed Animation of changing the State variable somehow has a reservation of some sort of that Variale but I could not find anything regarding this, yet.

```
             .overlay{
                if showAlert {
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                            .background(.gray)
                            .opacity(0.2)
                        ZStack{
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .fill(.ultraThickMaterial)
                            Group{
                                if saveSuccess {
                                    HStack{
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                                        Text("text1")
                                            
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    HStack{
                                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                                        Text("text2")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .font(.headline)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 60)
                    }
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        //cancel
                        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2)){
                            showAlert = false
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear{
                        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5).delay(1.5)){
                            showAlert = false
                        }
                    }
               }
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're right in your assumption that SwiftUI does schedule the change to occur after the specified delay. One approach would be to move your dismissal logic into a method for reusability. I have modified the `dismissAlert` method to include a `duration` input parameter which allows us to have the default of `0.2` for the dismissal, but also we can pass in the `0.5` that you want for an animation when `onAppear` performs the task. *This isn't required, but might be nice to have*.

```swift
private func dismissAlert(duration: TimeInterval = 0.2) {
    withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: duration)) {
        showAlert = false
    }
}
```

Then we can use the `.task` modifier that can be used on SwiftUI Views. This `Task` is performed asynchronously before the view appears which will then give us the delay. If the View is removed before the sleep finishes, the Task is cancelled. Inside of this Task, we can `sleep` to the requested time (in your example, there is a 1.5 second delay), and then perform the dismissal. The beauty of sleep is that it doesn't block the underlying thread - so the UI wont lock up.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAlert: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        // I excluded this because I dont know what your View looks like
        .overlay {
            if showAlert {
                ZStack {
                    // Your alert View goes here - excluded because I dont have it.
                }
                .task {
                    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_500_000_000)
                    dismissAlert(duration: 0.5)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    dismissAlert()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have now confirmed, that this solved my problem. The Animation including the delay does indeed stop any other code areas from initiating the dismissal. Although I find the necessity to use the sleep method for this not very appealing.

For completeness sake: I have read from another post on the apple forum, that this is the case, because the value is actually set immediately regardless how much delay or animation duration there is and the apple renderer makes sure to do it on time. So because the value is already set, the 2nd dismissal will never cause any data change and thus no animation